# CSS - Background over text

Tags: html, css

I have got `<span>` with some text. This span has got `background` property and I want to this background will be over the text. Here is my code:

```css
span {
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255,0,0,1) 0%, rgba(255,17,0,1) 100%);
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255,0,0,1) 0%, rgba(255,17,0,1) 100%);
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255,0,0,1) 0%, rgba(255,17,0,1) 100%);
background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255,0,0,1) 0%, rgba(255,17,0,1) 100%);
background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255,0,0,1) 0%, rgba(255,17,0,1) 100%);

background-size: 4px 6px;
background-repeat: repeat-x;
background-position: 0 .55em;

color: green;
font-size: 24pt;
}
```

```html
<span>SomeTextSomeText</span>
```

and I want to get:
[image]
without changing `background` property, using pseudo elements (`::after`, `::before`) or adding new elements. Is it possible? Thanks for help.

Comment: you have kind of ruled everything out so no it is not possible.  Can I ask why you're not willing to use a pseudo element?

Comment: @Pete yes. I don't want to use pseudo elements, because I want to make a lot of different strikeout effects like: dotted, thick, dashdot (-.-.-.) or dashdotdot (-..-..-..-..) and user can change color of strikeout. To do that I have to change inline CSS of strikeout element. It is possible when I use only normal element (not pseudo). To change pseudo-element I have to add separated `<style>` element and I don't want to do that

Comment: instead of changing inline css, why not just change the class(es) on the span?  You should try not to use any inline css unless it is absolutely necessary as it will become a maintenance nightmare

Comment: because there are a lot of colors

Comment: Well as you can see you are limiting yourself to what you can do, I would rather a class (or mixture of classes)  rather than a hack or not being able to do what I want.  It will also help to keep the size of your html file down in the long run as you will not be repeating common styles over and over in the inline styles

Comment: Maybe adding classes is good idea, but I must limit colors. @Pete thank you anyway

Comment: Basically...NO. You've eliminated all of the possible options. You can't have a background on top of an element and you have ruled out the obvious pseudo-element, Other than an **actual** element you are out of options.

Comment: You limit the colours in the same way you would do if you were using inline styles?  I still don't see the problem

Comment: can you show use the `lot of colors` ? like @pete said i don't see the issue of using classes, pseudo element,etc

Comment: @TemaniAfif OK I will explain. I have got WYSIWYG editor, and I am working on strikeouts. I create a lot of types of strikeouts like I said. User can select color (there are all RGB colors) and style of the line then click "apply". Function creates span element around selected text and adds inline style like `background-image: linear-gradient...` with previously selected colors. It is working but background is behind text. If I will use pseudo elements I have to add separated `<style>` element to `<head>` or somewhere **and** I have to add ID to that span. That would be a terrible mess.

Answer (score 4):

Why not use the `text-decoration` property?

```css
span {
  text-decoration: line-through red;
  color: green;
  font-size: 24pt;
}
```

```html
<span>SomeTextSomeText</span>
```

Comment: Yes, it is good idea, but I want to make a lot of different strikeout effects like: dotted, thick, dashdot (-.-.-.) or dashdotdot (-..-..-..-..) and I can't do it using `text-decoration`, but I can do it using `background` and `linear-gradient`